# WiX get culture preprocessor variable

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix-extension

I have a folder struckture like

```
[MyApp]
--[Videos]
  --[de-de]
    -video1.mpg
    - blah blah blah
  --[en-us]
    - video1.mpg
    - blah blah blah
etc etc
```

To include this videos to languagespecific installers i need an ability to access something like $(var.Culture) (<--didnt exist).
I tried to use the language files

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="Localisation">en-us</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

but that also doenst work cause they arent preprocessor variables so i cant use them in the "candle" process.
Is there any way to get the culturecode as a preprocessor variable for the current builded msi? Im sorry if this question is trivial but i searched google and i didnt find a real solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your localization variable:

```
<File Id="fileVideo1" Source="!(loc.Localisation)\video1.mpg"/>
```

Candle will take value from localization file for each culture.